# google-api-java-client create time series can be offline?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I am using the google-api-java-client to add my program metrics
 The code I am using (Java):

```
Create x = monitoringService.projects().timeSeries().create(PROJECT_RESOURCE, timeSeriesRequest);
x.execute();
```

Can the "x.excute() be run not on my thread (offline)" ?

Is there in the API the possibility to execute and continue (not blocking) ?

Or do I need to implement this by myself (by future) ?

Comment: I think you are using "offline" incorrectly. Considering this is a Google api and requires internet and all... You probably mean "asynchronously"? In which case, yeah, you can wrap that method in a `Thread`